# Get list of all the Project collection Admins for an organisation in azure devops

Tags: powershell, rest, azure-devops, scripting, azure-devops-rest-api

I want to list all the users in Project collection admin group in Azure devops. I am able to retrieve the list of users who are directly added and the users who are added through aad groups. But, I am unable to get the list of users who are added through built-in groups. For example, If Project collection admin group has some group called Project Collection Service accounts and that has another group called Enterprise Accounts and the Enterprise Accounts have some users like abc@gmail.com. Now if I fetch the list of PCA's I have to get abc@gmail.com in the list of all PCA's. Please let me know how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the REST API "[**Members - Get**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/members/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1)" to get the direct members of PCA group. Then recursively use the same API to get the direct members of the member groups of PCA.

You also can try using the Azure CLI "[**az devops security group membership list**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/devops/security/group/membership?view=azure-cli-latest#az-devops-security-group-membership-list)" to do the same things.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply! For Rest-API How to get the group entitlement ID's for groups?

Comment: @PrathyushaMandala
you can use this API "[Group Entitlements - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/group-entitlements/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1)" list the group entitlements and their IDs.